# Calling procedure through Snowsql

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am calling strored procedure thorugh SNOWSQL and getting below error.

> 002141 (42601): SQL compilation error:
> Unknown user-defined function ETL_SCHEMA.PROC

Below is the snowsql query:

```
snowsql -c newConnection  -o log_level=DEBUG -r ACCT_ROLE  -w ETL_XS_WH -d ETL_DEV_DB -s ETL_SCHEMA -q "CALL ETL_SCHEMA.PROC('202')" -o friendly=False  -o header=False -o output_format=plain -o timing=False
```

Is anything is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Is `CALL ETL_SCHEMA.PROC('202')` working in your Snowflake Web GUI? Maybe its not a Stored Procedure but an User defined function.

Comment: yes it is working fine when i am running in Web GUI

Answer (score -1):

The issue you are having is either permissions based or it's a search path issue.

I'd recommend prefixing the "etl_schema" with the database name (aka fully qualified name), and trying that.  You can also simply run a `select current_role(), current_database(), current_schema();` command instead of the call command to see what the context is, you might have something in the config that is overwriting the arguments passed in via the command.

Comment: Thanks Rich, i have checked i am able to run the the procedure from WEB UI, but from snowsql not able to run it. below is the shell script which i am using to run the procedure.

`#!/bin/ksh
export SNOWSQL_ACCOUNT=accountname;
export SNOWSQL_USER=useid;
export SNOWSQL_PWD=Password;
export SNOWSQL_DATABASE=DEV_DB;
export SNOWSQL_SCHEMA=ETL_SCHEMA;

snowsql -a $SNOWSQL_ACCOUNT -u $SNOWSQL_USER --variable SNOWSQL_PWD=$SNOWSQL_PWD -o log_level=DEBUG -o log_file=~/snowsql_sso_debug.log -r SRVC_ACCT_ROLE  -w ETL_XS_WH -d DEV_DB -s ETL_SCHEMA -q "CALL ETL_SCHEMA.PROC('202')"
`

Comment: please try ^ that (what you wrote) but replace the SQL command with the one I provided, to check your session "context".

Comment: schema does not exists, that is why it is throwing error.
i will check once the schema is available and will update my comment, Thank you!